# JavaFx TableView contents are disappeared after obfuscation

Tags: ant, tableview, javafx, obfuscation, proguard

I have created one JavaFX application that have many TableView to show content, application works fine if I run Jar file. As I need to distribute application to my clients so my code should be obfuscated. I am using Proguard-4.8 for obfuscation of my code.

I have created one sample TableView build script using Ant that obfuscate sample jar.

Before Obfuscation complied jar only -

[image: Before Obfuscation]

After Obfuscation Jar -

[image: After Obfuscation]

I have uploaded my complete build script project at - 
http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/SampleObfuscationBuildScript.zip

I have completely run it. You will find -

1. build.xml -
   http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/SampleObfuscationBuildScript/build.xml
2. Compiled Jar without obfuscation - http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/SampleObfuscationBuildScript/Sample.jar
3. Obfuscated Jar - http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/SampleObfuscationBuildScript/obfuscated/SampleObfuscated.jar
4. Proguard.map - http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/SampleObfuscationBuildScript/obfuscated/ObfuscatedProguard.map
5. Source Java Class - http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/SampleObfuscationBuildScript/src/TableViewWithButton.java

Other things is that -
This is my build.xml file -

```
<project name="sample" default="cleanBuildPackage" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <property environment="env"/>


    <property name="WorkingFolder" location="."/>
    <property name="ClassPath" location="${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar;${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar;${WorkingFolder}/lib/proguard.jar;"/>
    <property name="dist" value="dist"/>  
    <property name="main.class" value="TableViewWithButton"/>
    <property name="app.name" value="Sample"/>


    <target name="init">
        <echo message="Java installation directory: ${java.home}"/>
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp/>

        <delete dir="${WorkingFolder}/build"/>
        <delete dir="${dist}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${WorkingFolder}/build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="CompilingSample" depends="init">
        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
             uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpath=".;${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"/>
        <javac classpath="${ClassPath};" srcdir="${WorkingFolder}/src" destdir="${WorkingFolder}/build"/>
    </target> 



    <target name="CreatingSampleJar" depends="CompilingSample" description="generate the distribution" >
        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpath="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <fx:jar destfile="${WorkingFolder}/${app.name}.jar">
                    <fx:application mainClass="${main.class}"/>
                <fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/build"/>
            </fx:jar>
    </target> 

    <target name="Ofuscating" depends="CreatingSampleJar" >

        <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="${WorkingFolder}/lib/proguard.jar" />
            <mkdir dir="obfuscated"/>
                <proguard printmapping="obfuscated/ObfuscatedProguard.map"
                                renamesourcefileattribute="SourceFile" ignorewarnings="true">

                    -dontshrink
                    -dontoptimize

                    -libraryjars "${java.home}/lib/rt.jar"
                    -libraryjars "${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar"
                    -libraryjars "${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"
                    -libraryjars "${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"           


                    -injars ${WorkingFolder}/${app.name}.jar                                    

                    -outjars ${WorkingFolder}/Obfuscated.jar

                    -ignorewarnings

                    <keepattribute name="InnerClasses" />
                        <keepattribute name="SourceFile" />
                        <keepattribute name="LineNumberTable" />
                        <keepattribute name="Deprecated" />
                        <keepattribute name="*Annotation*" />
                        <keepattribute name="Signature" />

                    -adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,images/*,publicCerts.store,.version

                            <!--  
                            If I am adding this then I am able to see TableView Contents, but it do not obfuscate all public classes and their methods.
                            <keep access="public">
                                                 <method access="public protected" />
                                        </keep> 
                                         -->

                    -keepclassmembernames class * {
                        @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
                    } 
                    -keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, TableViewWithButton {
                            public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
                    }                    
            </proguard>


    </target>

    <target name="Movejar" depends="Ofuscating">
        <move
        file="${WorkingFolder}/Obfuscated.jar"
        tofile="obfuscated/${app.name}Obfuscated.jar" verbose="true" overwrite="true" />
    </target>



    <target name="cleanBuildPackage" depends="Movejar">
            <fx:deploy width="800" height="600" nativeBundles="all" outdir="${dist}" outfile="${app.name}">
                <fx:info title="${app.name}"/>
                    <fx:application name="${app.name}" mainClass="${main.class}"/>
                    <fx:resources>
                        <fx:fileset dir="${dist}" includes="*.jar"/>
             </fx:resources>
         </fx:deploy>
    </target>

</project>
```

In build.xml if I add this lines then I am able to see TableView Contents, but it do not obfuscate all public classes and their methods.

```
<keep access="public">
     <method access="public protected" />
</keep>
```

I need my project completely obfuscated. Is there other way to obfuscate jar file without keeping public classes UN-obfuscated so that I am able to see TableView text completely.

Thanks,

Neelam Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest trying to use the long form of **PropertyValueFactory**:

```
col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Test, String>,
             ObservableValue<String>>() {
     public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Test, String> t) {
         // t.getValue() returns the Test instance for a particular TableView row
         return t.getValue().testProperty();
         // or
         return new SimpleStringProperty(t.getValue().getMessage());
     }
  });
```